# Is there a way I can develop react in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ecmascript-6, create-react-app

I am new to react and I am currently studying with a book.
This book uses nodejs, and makes react project with "create-react-app" package.
I can surely use VSCode when developing this react project.
But I want to make back-end with Java using servlet, using Apache-tomcat.

I tried to open a new project made with

```
npx create-react-app newproject
```

And it seems that eclipse cannot detect this as a project.

My Eclipse is 2020-06 version, and it says that I have ECMAScript3 Library.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Eclipse's own project, [Wild Web Developer](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-wild-web-developer-html-css-javascript-typescript-json-yaml-xml-nodejs) aka WWD. It supports React and much more.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [CodeMix](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/react-codemix) - you can watch a video covering some of the features [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fzEe67P2DrU).

Note: I work for Genuitec, makers of CodeMix.